# Modifying JSfiddle for two sliding columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-animations

I came across this fiddle:
[JSfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/274NN/5/)

What I would like to do is have a second trigger to slide in a column from the right as well as the existing one that comes in from the left.

I didn't see anything about it in my search but I could be using the wrong tags.

Comment: Do you mean like this one ? http://fiddle.jshell.net/274NN/507/

Comment: Oops, actually, slightly different. There is a center main div with the buttons and the left and right columns come in from off screen.

Comment: -------------------------------
|                                          |
|      left               right         |
|_______________________|

Right button clicked:

-------------------------------
|        |                                 |
|        |            right col        |
|____ |__________________|

Same if left clicked but opposite direction

Comment: Check this updated version and let me know if it satisfies your requirement, so that I can post it as an answer.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/274NN/508/

Comment: Almost, tried to draw it above. No left and right visible, just center div. They show when clicked. Center compresses to left side as right col takes over. Same if left button clicked and left col takes over compressing center to right side.

Comment: but that last design gave me another ida for something so I'm using that too... lol

Comment: Also noticed that the bootstrap version in that fiddle was 2.1.1 which, when I changed the links to the latest, broke the sliding for me.